# 2点間の距離を求める

Tags: c

タイトルのように、2点間の距離を求めるために以下のようにプログラムしました。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define sqr(n) ((n)*(n)) /*2乗値を求める*/
/*===点の座標を表す構造体===*/
typedef struct {
    double x; /*X座標*/
    double y; /*Y座標*/
}  Point;
/*---点paと点pbの距離を返す---*/
double distance_of(Point pa,Point pb)
{
    return sqrt(sqr(pa.x-pb.x)+sqr(pa.y-pb.y));
}

int main(void)
{
    Point crnt,dest;
    printf("現在地のX座標: "); scanf("%lf",&crnt.x);
    printf("現在地のY座標: "); scanf("%lf",&crnt.y);
    printf("目的地のX座標: "); scanf("%lf",&dest.x);
    printf("目的地のY座標: "); scanf("%lf",&dest.y);

    printf("目的地までの距離は%.2fです。\n",distance_of(crnt,dest));
    return 0;

}
```

ですが、次のようなエラーが出てしまいました。

```
/tmp/ccvgfvhz.o: 関数 `distance_of' 内:
ex1108.c:(.text+0x9c): `sqrt' に対する定義されていない参照です
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

そもそも、自分は `<math.h>` に平方根を計算する関数sqrtがあると認識していましたが
それは誤認で、sqrt関数を定める必要があるということでしょうか。
だとすれば、sqrt関数はどのように定めればよいでしょうか。

Comment: 過去の質問も含め、タイトルが課題か何かのままになっていますが、実際の困りごとなどに焦点を絞ったものを付けることを心がけてみてください。例えば今回の場合も「2点間の距離の求め方」が分からないわけではないですよね？ / 質問の仕方についてはヘルプも参考にしてみてください。 - [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問環境がわかりませんが、とりあえず[Linux用の`sqrt`のドキュメント](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/LDP_man-pages/man3/sqrt.3.html)には

> `-lm` でリンクする。

と説明されています。他の環境でもだいたい同じでコンパイル（正確にはリンク）時に`-lm`オプションを指定する必要があります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。平方根を使うときは-lmでコンパイルできるということを知らなかったので、勉強になりました。